# Can I use different fonts for different languages in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm a multilingual speaker and a lot of times I need to make plots with a mixture of different languages (for example, English and Chinese). I wonder if there is a way to use different fonts for different languages in ggplot2? For example:

```
library(showtext)
  Loading required package: sysfonts
  Loading required package: showtextdb
library(ggplot2)

showtext_auto()

font_add_google('Roboto')
font_add_google('Long Cang')

font_families()
[1] "sans"         "serif"        "mono"         "wqy-microhei" "Roboto"       "Long Cang" 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'A. This is the main title 中文标题') +  
  theme_classic(base_family = 'Roboto')

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'B. This is the main title 中文标题') +  
  theme_classic(base_family = 'Long Cang')
```

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to use "Roboto" for English characters/numbers and "Long Cang" for Chinese characters in the same plot?

Any comment would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One option to use different fonts would be the `ggtext` package which allows for styling via HTML/CSS. Unfortunately I had some encoding issues on my Windows machine so I could only show you an example of the general approach which uses the default `serif` font and the `Roboto` font for the title:

```r
library(showtext)
library(ggplot2)

showtext_auto()

font_add_google('Roboto')

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = paste('This is the main title',
  "<span style='font-family: Roboto;'>Roboto</span>")) +
  theme_classic(base_family = 'serif') +
  theme(plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]